# SQL MAX() - increase performance of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following select query:

```
SELECT 
    a.PatientId,
    MAX(a.CreatedAtUtc) AS last_sync
FROM 
    [dbo].[Epochs] AS a
WHERE 
    a.PatientId IN (3, 720, 709)
GROUP BY 
    a.PatientId
```

Is there another way to get max `CreatedAtUtc` without the `MAX()` aggregate function? Maybe I can somehow take `TOP(1) a.CreatedAtUtc FROM [dbo].[Epochs] ORDER BY CreatedAtUtc DESC` or something like this?

Initial data:

```
PatientId | CreatedAtUtc
----------+-------------------------
3         | 2021-01-14 16:22:42.760
3         | 2021-01-05 06:03:07.107
3         | 2021-01-10 15:11:28.967
709       | 2021-01-19 16:22:42.760
709       | 2021-02-10 06:03:07.107
720       | 2021-01-10 15:11:28.967
720       | 2021-02-10 15:11:28.967
```

Expected result:

```
PatientId | last_sync
----------+-------------------------
3         | 2021-01-14 16:22:42.760
709       | 2021-02-10 06:03:07.107
720       | 2021-02-10 15:11:28.967
```

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) What is wrong with `MAX()` to get the maximum value?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT e.PatientId,
       MAX(e.CreatedAtUtc) AS last_sync
FROM [dbo].[Epochs] e
WHERE e.PatientId IN (3, 720, 709)
GROUP BY e.PatientId;
```

Most databases can use an index on `Epochs(PatientId, CreatedAtUtc)` to increase performance.  Some can use the index directly, but most will need to aggregate still.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is that your query is slow, and you think that the MAX function is the cause of it.  It can be, if you don't have an index on the column.

If you call `MAX(CreatedAtUtc)` and you don't have an index on the `CreatedAtUtc` column, then the DB must look at every record in the database to find the max value.

If you do have an index on `CreatedAtUtc`, then the DB just looks at the index and gives you the answer.

So, get an index on that column.

```
CREATE INDEX EpochsCreatedAtUtc ON Epochs(CreatedAtUtc);
```

As Gordon Linoff points out above, you really need an index on both patientId and CreatedAtUtc, because both of those are used for selection.

```
CREATE INDEX EpochsWhatever ON Epochs(PatientId, CreatedAtUtc);
```

Take a look at https://use-the-index-luke.com/ for a good introduction on how to use indexes.